# WinRT XAML Toolkit LineSeries Is it possible to change Style of only one line in the series?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, silverlight-toolkit, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I have a line series chart with several lines in the series.  Is it possible for me to change one of the lines to a dashed line with a different thickness and leave the others as is?  Any and all guidance appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - the [`LineSeries`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/Charting/Series/LineSeries.xaml) is represented by just a [`Polyline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.polyline.aspx) which is a single shape and if I understand you correctly - you would like to style one of its segments differently.

If you look at the code for the [`LineSeries`](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/Charting/Series/LineSeries.cs) though - it seems fairly straightforward. Perhaps you could implement something like a `SegmentedLineSeries` that applies different styling to different segments. It would probably be similar to `LineSeries`, but instead of just a `PointsCollection Points` property you would need to have a list of pairs of points to draw different segments on a `Canvas`. Your template then might have an `ItemsControl` with `ItemsPanel` set to a canvas and `ItemTemplate` being a `Line` shape with X1,Y1 and X2,Y2 bound to your segment collection.